# Search API tags vocabulary facet help

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, search

I have a site setup with Search API and Solr, everything is working as expected except for what I am trying to do with facets.

Each content type has tags using the tags vocabulary, I have created the facets for each content type, which works.  But what I am trying to have is a tag facet that isn't split into its content type.

What I want is so that users can narrow their search down seeing all content types with the tags they select, rather than having a facet tag list for each content type.

Does anyone know of a way to create this type of facet?

Comment: Do you have different search indexes for different content types (or set them to specific content types)? You could try to have one big search index for all content types and then also create a facet for the content type. That way users should be able to narrow down either by taxonomy and/or by content type.

Comment: I have one search index for all the content types.  I am wondering if it is because I have changed the machine name for the tags on each content type.  They use the same vocabulary but different machine names.

Comment: Search API uses the tag id (tid). So if you have two different tags with the same name it won't work.

Comment: So if I have an article with the tag "foo" and a resource with the tag "foo", is it not possible to have a single facet?

It works with drupal's regular tag view e.g. "foo" would show all articles and all resource's with the tag.

Comment: You meant machine names for the fields or the tags? Fields should not matter, different machine names for the tags would imply different tags which won't work.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.  Yeah what I've done wrong then is created different fields but used the same vocabulary.  What I should have done when creating the content types is added the existing tag field.  I can see this is going to be a bit of a nightmare to fix.